# List data structure in SQL using another table's records as elements

Tags: sql, list

How would I define a field in a table that is a list (could even be a set), but the elements in the list are all records in another table?

Ideally I would have something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ListElements (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE TableWithList (
    ID int,
    SomeField varchar(255),
    AList List(ListElements)
)
```

The only solution can I can think of at the moment is to have *AList* be a string (TEXT) that lists the IDs of all the list elements.

Are there any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Element (
   ID int,
   Name varchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE List (
   ID int,
   ListName varchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE ListsElements (
   ElementID int,
   ListID int
)
```

The `ListID` in `ListsElements` would correspond to the `ID` in `List` and the `ElementID` in `ListsElements` would correspond to the `ID` in `Element`.

When you change an `Element`, it will change in all lists.

If you have different types of elements, this could still work.  Just add a field to `ListsElements` with the type of element it is.  You would still have a table for all the different types of elements (no real way around that) but only one table for lists and their relationships.

Comment: Ok, but the ListElement isn't primarily just used as a list element, it is also used for other things. Which means that if I want it to be in more than one list then I will have to have two records with the same information. I could make ListElement contain the ID of the data in yet another table but then I'm starting to get quite a lot of tables just for a list...

Comment: Yup, I see now. I was hoping for a way that didn't require adding two many tables, because I have several different types of list element, so this would require adding quite a few more tables. But thanks heaps, this is indeed a good solution.

Comment: Trust me @DanieL when I tell you that this solution will be much easier to maintain and is a textbook example of how to deal with our problem.  +1 for a 3rd normal form solution :)

Comment: Ok, will do. I think I can condense it so I have a few less tables too. Thanks.

Comment: @Danial. Why are you bothered about the number of tables? If you need three tables than use three tables. Some real world databases have 4000 plus tables doesn't seem to cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

just make a reference to the list from the table that you are trying to cram the list into now and then you'll have the best of both worlds.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand you. Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: @DanieL sorry for being unclear, let me explain. In table A let's say you have some data and in one of the columns you are storing a list, let's just assume the list is in a text field. The problem you've stated is that you don't want to the list to be saved in a text column because you aren't really preserving the fact the it's a list. Thus my proposed solution is instead of keeping the list in table A in a text field, create a new table B that only contains the attributes of the list that was previously saved in a text field in table A, and be sure to of course link both tables with FK's.

Comment: Ok, this seems like it would require a new table for each list, is that right?

Comment: @DanieL having a table for each list would be very wasteful potentially. In the lists are similar than make 1 table and just have a single row in the table represent a list.

Comment: Hmm, the tables that the list elements are in will vary depending on the list so I don't think that I can do a generic list structure this way.

Comment: @DanieL then maybe you can just use a delimiter in the list and store it as a text field after all. Parsing the string with a known delimiter should not pose any major performance losses, unless your lists grow significantly.

Comment: Ok, I think i'm going to play around with a few different ways of doing it and see which one I prefer, thanks for your help!